# ¿Alguien sabe por qué cuando hago mi deployment de un proyecto de create-react-app no me funciona?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localhost, deployment

En el **localhost** si funciona el proyecto, pero el **deployment** se pierde toda la funcionalidad del proyecto. Esto es lo que me aparece en la consola del navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La petición que haces a newsapi.org tiene que ser por protocolo https

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Asi es como estoy haciendo la petición:  _consultarNoticias = async (categoria = "general") => {
    const url = `http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=co&category=${categoria}&apiKey=d3e3c23a83f14ca9b5907f1cb8a78438`;
    const dataRequest = {
      method: "GET",
    };

    const respuesta = await fetch(url, dataRequest);
    const noticiasApi = await respuesta.json();
    // console.log(noticias.articles[0]);

    this.setState({
      noticias: noticiasApi.articles,
    });
  };